# WinDbg !htrace -diff busy forever

Tags: windbg

I have to debug a huge Windows server application which we think has handle leaks.

What I'm doing:

```
Run WinDbg as administrator

Attach to process

!htrace -enable

!htrace -snapshot

g

Run test scenario

Ctrl-break

!htrace -diff
```

At this point my WinDbg show `*Busy*` status forever and print nothing.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to call `!htrace -snapshot` as the first time you enable it, it takes a snapshot. Secondly if you application is running for a while and it's consumed a lot of memory and handles then this will take some time. Does the task manager show cpu activity for windbg? Do you know what kind of handles you are leaking? You may find using appplication verifier which ships with MS debugging tools a better tool for this as will trace and if windbg is attached throw an exception to debug break the application when something erroneous occurs

Comment: @EdChum , yes I see WinDbg consumes about  13% for some hours. And still prints nothing. Looks like it is a job WinDbg cannot manage.

Comment: If it's taking that long you need to do some more work to understand what type of handles are leaking and whether you can prove this before you do this. Also do you need to run the application for a long time before breaking in and doing a diff? I suggest using app verifier first and try to understand what type of handle is leaking first

Comment: @EdChum. I did give a try to application verifier, it produced huge listing which I expect contains a lots of false positives.

Comment: You can set the individual events and breaks in app verifier, for instance for critical section leaks, threads, handles etc.. Do you have ideas whether you are leaking file handles, events, critical sections, reg keys.. etc? Have you tried running, breaking, diffing on shorter runs?

Comment: @EdChum, yes, I did it. I run WinDbg for short time, select only handle leaks with app verifier. The only way I see at the moment is to count opening/closing handles in the code using the statistics from app verifier. Start from the modules which has bigger handle statistic.

Comment: There aren't many options with `!htrace` other than specifying the max number of traces, really at this stage you need to narrow the problem down further. Try to find out the type of handle if possible (you can use proc mon to monitor this in real time, won't tell what's leaking but it will indicate what is happening), look at your code to identify where handles are being opened, you can keep a count and log when they open/close. Reduce the size of your app to to the minimum needed to reproduce the issue, or call some suspect code in a loop 1000 times and count the no handles before/after